# Application freezing while fetching large data from core data base

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using Core data, and trying to get large amount of data at a time using code

```
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But my main thread is freezing. How can I fetch my data on background thread ?
[In apple documentation its given on link in column "Fetch in the Background for UI Responsiveness"][1]

But There is no sample code to implement it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourMethodName) withObject:nil];
```

if you dont need to pass any parameters to that method.. leave nil at the end

in that method wich you are calling handle your fetching

Comment: i have multiple parameters. Also please see this link i need this solution https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW6

Comment: It is basically the same as i suggested. You can put your parameters into struct and pass it as one.